# Why are AND instructions generated?

Tags: c#, .net, assembly

For code such as this:

```
int res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    res += 1 << i;
}
```

This code is generated (release mode, no debugger attached, 64bit):

```
 xor edx,edx 
 mov r8d,1 
_loop:
 lea ecx,[r8-1] 
 and ecx,1Fh     ; why?
 mov eax,1 
 shl eax,cl 
 add edx,eax 
 mov ecx,r8d 
 and ecx,1Fh     ; why?
 mov eax,1 
 shl eax,cl 
 add edx,eax 
 lea ecx,[r8+1] 
 and ecx,1Fh     ; why?
 mov eax,1 
 shl eax,cl 
 add edx,eax 
 lea ecx,[r8+2] 
 and ecx,1Fh     ; why?
 mov eax,1 
 shl eax,cl 
 add edx,eax 
 add r8d,4 
 cmp r8d,21h 
 jl  _loop
```

Now I can see the point of most instructions there, but what's up with the AND instructions? ecx will *never* be more than 0x1F in this code anyway, but I excuse it for not noticing that (and also for not noticing that the result is a constant), it's not an ahead-of-time compiler that can afford to spend much time on analysis after all. But more importantly, SHL with a 32bit operand masks cl by 0x1F already. So it seems to me that these ANDs are entirely useless. Why are they generated? Do they have some purpose I'm missing?

Comment: Out of interest, do you have a link about SHL already masking? I've looked in a couple of places but failed to find any statement to that effect. (Strike that - just found it.)

Comment: Not an expert - so excuse if stupid question, but how does the `cl` register get populated. Is the `and` operation the fastest way for it to populate that perhaps?

Comment: This whole generated code seems giberish to me.  why break a simple instruction batch up into so many sub batches? i dont have visual studio available right now but i really have a hard time believing that JIT compiler produces this type of assembly.....

Comment: @Polity It's unrolled the loop, so it looks a lot worse than it is.

Comment: It's unrolled by 4, and cl gets populated by the mov/lea into ecx.

Comment: @Polity you do have a point though. Although it only loops 8 times now instead of 32, it does have more complicated lookups (like [r8+2] instead of only [r8]), so I doubt it gains much.

Comment: It doesn't, despite the unrolling it has a loop-carried dependency on edx. They should have split that accumulator and merged it in the end. Or not, and not unroll. But yea it's a JIT compiler, it has to trade cleverness for speed. The lea with the offset doesn't cost anything, by the way. But they could have used ecx as the loop counter and not have that mov/lea at all.

Comment: finally, a question tagged .net and assembly that's not about .net-assemblies :D

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `and` is already present in the CIL code emitted by the C# compiler:

```
    IL_0009: ldc.i4.s 31
    IL_000b: and
    IL_000c: shl
```

The spec for the CIL `shl` instruction says:

> The return value is unspecified if *shiftAmount* is greater than or equal to the size of *value*.

The C# spec, however, defines the 32-bit shift to take the shift count mod 32:

> When the type of *x* is `int` or `uint,` the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of count. In other words, the shift count is computed from `count & 0x1F`.

In this situation, the C# compiler can’t really do much better than emit an explicit `and` operation. Best you can hope for is that the JITter will notice this and optimize away the redundant `and`, but that takes time, and the speed of JIT is pretty important. So consider this the price paid for a JIT-based system.

The real question, I guess, is why the CIL specifies the `shl` instruction that way, when C# and x86 both specify the truncating behaviour. That I do not know, but I speculate that it’s important for the CIL spec to avoid specifying a behaviour that may JIT to something expensive on some instruction sets. At the same time, it’s important for C# to have as few undefined behaviours as possible, because people invariably end up using such undefined behaviours until the next version of the compiler/framework/OS/whatever changes them, breaking the code.

Comment: On x64, shl truncates the shift value at 64 bits which can lead to some nasty surprises when shifting 64-bit values and moving from x86 to x64.

Comment: If the CIL `shl` was defined as truncating, surely the most expensive thing that needed to be done was the same AND that wasn't avoided now anyway?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I did consider that, but I don’t have an x64 spec handy, and the only reference I could find _seemed_ to suggest that a `shl eax` will truncate to 32, just like it would on x86. Is this not so?

Comment: @harold you are of course right that the net effect is the same. The difference is that the JITter is not inserting such operations, and someone coding in raw IL can reliably avoid the cost. They wouldn’t be able to on _some_ CPUs if the truncating behaviour was mandatory (in the absence of a smarter jitter, anyway).

Comment: @romkyns No. You have the `mod 32` behavior only in 32 bit compatibility mode, which is, indeed, compatible to x86. In x86_64 shifts are always `mod 64`.

Comment: @drhirsch Intels manual says mod64 only applies to REX.W-ed instructions though

Comment: @harold Yes, you are right. Yet another inconsistency in this architecture, as if there weren't already enough.

Comment: @drhirsch I like this one actually, saves an AND for 32bit shifts.. oh wait :)

Answer (score 10):

x64 cores already apply the 5 bit mask to the shift amount.  From the Intel Processor manual, volume 2B page 4-362:

> The destination operand can be a register or a memory location.  The count operand can be an immediate value or the CL register.  **The count is masked to 5 bits** (or 6 bits if in 64-bit mode and REG.W is used).  A special opcode encoding is provided for a count of 1.

So that's machine code that isn't necessary.  Unfortunately, the C# compiler cannot make any assumptions about the processor's behavior and must apply C# language rules.  And generate IL whose behavior is specified in the CLI specification.  Ecma-335, Partion III, chapter 3.58 says this about the SHL opcode:

> The shl instruction shifts value (int32, int64 or native int) left by the number of bits specified by shiftAmount. shiftAmount is of type int32 or native int. **The return value is unspecified if shiftAmount is greater than or equal to the width of value**.

**Unspecified** is the rub here.  Bolting specified behavior on top of unspecified implementation details produces the unnecessary code.  Technically the jitter could optimize the opcode away.  Although that's tricky, it doesn't know the language rule.  Any language that specifies no masking will have a hard time generating proper IL.  You can post to connect.microsoft.com to get the jitter team's view on the matter.

Answer (score 5):

C# compiler has to insert these AND instructions while generating intermediate (machine-independent) code, because C# left shift operator is required to use only 5 least significant bits.

While generating x86 code, optimizing compiler may drop these unneeded instructions. But, apparently, it skips this optimization (probably, because it cannot afford to spend much time on analysis).