# Is it possible to gain performance in vm-based languages by hand-writing code in their assembly?

Tags: assembly, bytecode, vm-implementation

I know it probably wouldn't make much sense to do it as usually it's faster and more logical to just rewrite performance-critical sections in a faster language, but setting that aside, is it possible to write faster CPython/JVM/CLR programs by writing portions directly in their assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is. Not often mind you, but I know of [at least one case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905668/why-are-and-instructions-generated) (skipping the `and` in MSIL makes that code a tiny bit faster). There are probably more cases, the CLR JIT compiler isn't all that smart.

Comment: To me this sounds like a heavily specific case, but if I knew better I wouldn't be asking ^^

Comment: @Asmageddon well it's an example. The C# and Java compilers don't do many optimizations and instead rely on the JIT compiler to fix things up, which sometimes doesn't do it either (possibly because it can't spend too much time on analysis). In those cases you can help the JIT by writing smarter IL.

Comment: Sounds logical. What is your opinion on the other two answers?

Comment: @Asmageddon they're not really wrong, but IMO they avoid answering the actual question. Sure, it's hard to find situations where it helps, and not recommended and all that.. but the answer should still be "yes you can in select cases".

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not recommended. For example, the Just-In-Time compilation feature in some JVMs searches for bytecode patterns to optimise  them significantly at runtime. If you substitute them with your own twisted bytecode, JIT might not work and you will end up with a slower code. This is what happens sometimes when you obfuscate Java programs.

Comment: Not recommended is not "impossible". You could always write the same thing as the compiler, so you won't do worse unless you're just doing it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

No. The bytecode for most high level languages is very high level, and usually corresponds well with that idioms that language uses - you simply can't write the code to do a simple task any way other than what the compiler already emits, at least not without making it slower.

Most speedup from hand crafted assembler comes from clever register usage, clever use of machine specific opcodes, etc - all things you have no control over when writing high level bytecode.

Also it's important to note that if you emit unusual code - say in some stack-based vm you notice a value is used twice, and being clever rather than emitting a temporary variable you leave it on the stack and dupe it later.. you've possibly just hit performance hard. The JIT no longer recognises the idiom, and emits awful code as a result. I've been hit by this firsthand emitting runtime generated MSIL - **if what you're emitting doesn't resemble compiler generated code, it's probably not going to perform.**

Of course I'm talking about MSIL here specifically - but I believe in general it will hold true.

Comment: Downvoter, can I ask why? My answer is pretty similar to H-H's in my opinion.

Comment: I should probably have added though that you may end up a percent either way. I assumed we were talking about **appreciable** performance gains here, the kind that may warrant emitting bytecode, not 1-2% gains that no user is ever going to notice.