# Differences in division and multiplication vs bit shifting

Tags: c#, performance, division, bit-shift

### DISCLAIMER

I do **not** want to know **when or if to use** shift operators in my code, I am interested in **why** multiplication is faster than shifting bits to the left whereas division is not.

---

As I was just wandering around SO I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168451/is-shifting-bits-faster-than-multiplying-and-dividing-in-java-net) question regarding efficiency and speed of division and bit shifting. It basically states that although one might save a few seconds when performing bit shifts on powers of 2, it is not some difference one has to worry about.

Intrigued by this I decided to check how much faster bit shifting in C# actually is and realised something strange:

> Bit shifting instead of dividing is faster, as I expected, but the "normal" multiplication method is faster than bit shifting.

My question is simple: Why is the multiplication of two numbers faster than bit shifting, although bit shifting is a primitive operation for the processor?

---

Here are the results for my test case:

```
           Division: | Multiplication:
Bit shift:   315ms   |   315ms
   normal:   406ms   |   261ms
```

The times are the averages of 100 cases with each case consisting of 10 operations per number on 10000000 random positive numbers ranging from 1 to `int.MaxValue`. The operations ranged from dividing/multiplying by 2 to 1024 (in powers of 2) and bit shifting from 1 to 10 digits.

---

### EDIT

@usr: I am using .NET version 4.5.1

I updated my results because I realised I only computed a tenth of the numbers I stated... *facepalm*

My Main:

```
static Main(string[] args)
{
    Fill(); // fills the array with random numbers
    Profile("division shift:", 100, BitShiftDiv);
    Profile("division:", 100, Div);
    Profile("multiplication shift:", 100, BitShiftMul);
    Profile("multiplication:", 100, Mul);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This is my profiling method:

```
static void Profile(string description, int iterations, Action func)
{
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    func();

    Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        func();
    }
    stopWatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(description);
    Console.WriteLine("total: {0}ms", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("  avg: {0}ms", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / (double)iterations);
}
```

The Actions containing the operations are structured like this:

```
static void <Name>()
{
    for (int s = 1; s <= 10; s++)    /* for shifts */
    for (int s = 2; s <= 1024; s++)  /* for others */ 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            var useless = nums[i] <shift> s;    /* shifting  */
            var useless = nums[i] <operator> s; /* otherwise */
        }
    }
}
```

`nums` is a public array containing `10000000` `int`s, which is filled by the `Fill()` method.

Comment: Because the optimizer is not stupid.

Comment: @SLaks Still even then I would expect it to be as fast as bit shifting and not faster.

Comment: Multiplication is also a primitive operation for the processor.

Comment: You're probably measuring wrongly; microbenchmarks are hard.

Comment: @Slaks Testing 50000000 random numbers yields a clearer result: about 195ms for bit shifting and about 175ms for multiplication.

Comment: You're probably still measuring wrongly.  Beware the JITter. http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/benchmark.html

Comment: @SLaks All right, thank you for your fast answer!

Comment: *"might save a few seconds when performing bit shifts"*... you are still using an i386?

Comment: @elgonzo Nope, I use an Intel i7.

Comment: FWIW, I reproduced @ThreeFx's results.

Comment: The idea that shifting is faster than multiplying was true in some badly optimized C compilers on 1970s hardware. Let the optimizer do it's job.

Comment: I'm not convinced about the compiler optimization argument, since we're using randomly-generated multiplicands here. I'm more inclined to believe that the multiplication is amortized due to instruction-level parallelism (superscalar pipelining).

Comment: Post the C# code and the generated x64 code. Release mode without debugger. What .NET version?

Comment: Could the downvoters explain why?

Comment: This kind of micro-optimizations are as good as out of reach for assembly programmers on modern hardware. From C# there are 2 compilers in front of that pipelined CPU. With _although bit shifting is a primitive operation for the processor_ you're already a mile off.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you that is (finally) a comment which actually answers the question I asked.

Comment: Shifts have extra overhead in C#, explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9906638/17034).  Not running with the optimizer enabled is a standard benchmark mistake.  Use Agner Fog's instruction timing manual to get insight.  Cycle times are an estimate: shifting a memory value by an arbitrary amount roughly takes 4 cycles, multiplication takes 1, dividing takes between 11 and 18 cycles.  These big differences are blurred by the for(;;) loop overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the answers already mentioned in the comments:

- Multiplication, as well as bit shifting, is faster because is a **native operation** for the CPU too. It takes one cycle while bit shifting takes about four which is why it is faster. Division takes something between 11 and 18 cycles.
- Using C# I cannot get close enough to the CPU to get diagnostically conclusive results because many optimizations take place between my code and the CPU.
- Also, microbenchmarking is hard and can produce erroneous results, which also can happen because of the above mentioned reason.

If I forgot anything, please comment and tell me!

Comment: As mentioned by Hans Passant, you should use a professional reference for how long instructions actually take, such as the one he recommended: https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf  Please note that it is never as easy as just "timings" either. For example multiplication on Zen4 has a latency of ~3 cycles before the result can be used, which is slower than shifting which has a latency of 1 cycle - but there is also the fact that the cpu can perform 2 shifts **per** cycle, so in an optimal case where you feed a lot of independent shifts then throughput is double the general case